# Java return ResponseEntity of two different types

Tags: java, rest

Trying to return a bad request error code in a catch block, otherwise returning a collection. Not sure how to set the method return type to handle both.

Rough pseudo code:

```
public ResponseEntity</*what goes here*/> getCollection() {
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(someCollection);
    } catch(SomeException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Is my approach incorrect to simply assume I can just set a generic type to handle both return types?

Comment: Why can't you give like `public ResponseEntity<Object> getCollection()`

Comment: @TomSebastian somehow that triggers an incompatible type error :S

Comment: My mistake you should give `public ResponseEntity<?> getCollection()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` as return type.`entity` can be JSON object

```
ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok(entity);
return rb.build();
```

Same way you can build entity JSON in catch block with proper error msg.

**OR**

Create custom class by extending `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException`.

Comment: What if I'm stuck with ResponseEntity as return type?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would do this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> getCollection() { // -> "Object is added between "<>"
    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(someCollection);
    } catch(SomeException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); // -> "String" is removed between "<>"
    }
}
```

`Object` is a parent class of all classes and Java has the ability to infer types. Because of that ability `body(someCollection)` will be returned as `ResponseEntity<Object>` type and `new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)` also.